# submit not work after inline ajax validation completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jquery validation engine for validating a password recovery form with an email field and a submit button. 
It checks with inline ajax validation that the email address is in the database. If I type in the email address and hit Enter the ajax validation works fine and the form is submitted. 
However I click on the submit button the email field is getting validated, but the form is not submitted.

```html
<form action="/lost-password" method="post" id="checkmail">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email],ajax[ajaxEmailCall]]"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send password" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

```js
$(function(){       
    $("#checkmail").validationEngine();     
});
```

Comment: What does your event binding look like? (perhaps it is handled by the plugin - not familiar with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button name from `name="submit"` to `name="btnSubmit"` and see if it makes a difference. If it works, the submit name is screwing up the form's submit method.